# Sorting the Date of Format DD.MM.YYYY in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have set of Data having date along with the list. I need to sort the fields. I am able to sort all other fields except Date. Find below the code.
And also if I sort the column "Name", the other two column's icon also changing. I want the solution like if i sort the particular column, that particular column arrow icon should change not other two columns icon.

So My Question is how to sort the date Column and and the icon of that particular column should only change when i tap on that particular column.

**HTML**

```
    <ion-row class="header-row">
      <ion-col size="1" tappable (click)="sortBy('Name')">
       <b>FirstName</b>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-down" *ngIf="sortDirection==1"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up" *ngIf="sortDirection==2"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col size="1" tappable (click)="SortBy('PurchaseDate')">
      <b>Purchase Date</b>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-down" *ngIf="sortDirection==1"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up" *ngIf="sortDirection==2"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>

      <ion-col size="1" tappable (click)="sortBy('CarName')">
      <b>Car Name</b>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-down" *ngIf="sortDirection==1"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up" *ngIf="sortDirection==2"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

     <ion-card class="cardbottomfield colpadding">
     <div *ngFor="let purchase of purchasedetails ; trackBy: trackByFn" class="data-row">
     <ion-row> 
       <ion-col size="1"> 
         {{purchase.Name}}
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col size="1" > 
        {{purchase.PurchaseDate}}
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col size="1">
        {{purchase.CarName}}
       </ion-col>      
       </ion-row>
       </div>
     </ion-card>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
     sortBy(key) {
      this.sortKey= key;
      this.sortDirection++;
      this.sort();
      }

      sort() {
        if(this.sortDirection == 1) {
          this.purchasedetails = this.purchasedetails.sort((a,b) => {
          const valA = a[this.sortKey];
          const valB = b[this.sortKey];
          return valA.localeCompare(valB);
         });

        } else if (this.sortDirection == 2) {
        this.purchasedetails = this.purchasedetails.sort((a,b) => {
        const valA = a[this.sortKey];
        const valB = b[this.sortKey];
        return valB.localeCompare(valA);
        });

       } else {
      this.sortDirection = 0;
      this.sortKey = null;
      }
     }
```

Comment: to sort DATE set the format to `YYYY-MM-DD` and then compare with greater than

Comment: I am not getting how to compare all the dates ( array is like 50 items). Thats y am asking. Can you please send me the code that how to do action. I need to sort both ascending and descending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create `Date` objects from date strings
2. Sort ascending based on `valueOf`

```js
const parseDate = (dateStr) => {
    const [d, m, y] = dateStr.split('.')
        .map(Number)

    return new Date(y, m - 1 /* month is 0-indexed */, d)
}

const sortDatesAsc = (dateStr1, dateStr2) => {
    return parseDate(dateStr2).valueOf - parseDate(dateStr1).valueOf
}

console.log([
    '10.01.2010',
    '01.10.2010',
    '10.10.2020',
].sort(sortDatesAsc))
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort an array of object by dates of format (`DD.MM.YYYY`)

```
datesObject.sort(function(a, b){
    let curr = a.date.split('.').reverse().join();
    let prev = b.date.split('.').reverse().join();
    return curr < prev ? -1 : (curr > prev ? 1 : 0);
});
```